# How do I verify that syndaemon is disabling the touchpad while I type?

Tags: touchpad

I thought that I had set syndaemon to disable the touchpad while I type, and for 0.8 seconds afterwards. In order to change the default touchpad delay of 2.0 seconds, which is hard-coded into the touchpad settings dialog, I unchecked "Disable touchpad while typing" and added "syndaemon -i 0.8 -K -R -t" to the list of startup applications. Most of the time now, the touchpad doesn't register taps while I type, as I want. However, sometimes while typing, the cursor still flicks to a random spot in the text box, even while I am in the middle of typing. I don't take anywhere near 0.8 seconds between keystrokes - what could be happening here?

To verify that syndaemon is running with the correct options when the unwanted behavior occurs, I run:

```
$ ps -ef | grep syndaemon
user      1840  1747  0 Sep23 ?        00:00:00 syndaemon -i 0.8 -K -R -t
```

Everything seems fine. What could the problem be? How do I go about finding out if syndaemon is to blame?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I never found a solution. It looks to me like a bug. I haven't updated to the newest version of Ubuntu yet, so it might have been fixed some time after 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

> -t  Only disable tapping and scrolling, not mouse movements, in response to keyboard activity.

See `man syndaemon` for more info.

Basically, you've disabled tapping and scrolling, but not movement with that command. Try something like this instead:

```
syndaemon -i 0.8 -K -R
```

Comment: I don't mind the movement of the pointer, which is why I use -t, but the moving of the keyboard input cursor (by tapping) is the problem.

Comment: What's "keyboard input cursor", and how many cursors are there?

Comment: The cursor is the thing in the textbox that shows you where the characters will appear if you type. The pointer is the thing that you move with your mouse. I said "keyboard input cursor" the second time to try to get that across.

Comment: I see. Did you get the same behavior when the timeout was 2 seconds?

Comment: Adjusting the timeout doesn't help. The timeout doesn't always hold. Often, while I am in the middle of typing a word, the cursor will jump to another point. The time between keystrokes in that case is on the order of 100-200ms, far shorter than any timeout I've ever set. For example, I was just typing '\*\*kwargs' in a python script. The first '\*' appeared in the correct position, but the second '\*', typed almost immediately afterwards (I double-tapped the key quickly), appeared at a different location, as the cursor had switched positions in between keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to make syndaemon work in its current incarnation is to disable the XRecord support (it doesn't seem to work at all), and use -m 50 (that is, poll every 50 milliseconds).

So:

```
syndaemon -m 50
```

However, this seems to make the keyboard lose keypresses and flip to "shift always down" modes and such instead, so essentially syndaemon seems to be useless.  The only way to use a touchpad is to manually disable the touchpad with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The -m 50 solved my weird "Won't wake up again" problem.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've been plagued with this problem for some time as well. I run in a terminal

```
while true; do synclient|grep TouchpadOff; sleep 0.5; done
```

Then type in a different window some keys.
I noticed that it outputs TouchpaddOff=1 as soon as you type small letters, but capitals (Shift+letter) are NOT disabling keypad. Cursor and mouse always jump when using capital letters. I looked in the syndaemon source, and it seems the -k and -K options are the culprit. If you press Shift to use a capital, the touchpad can get re-enabled. It's a bug. But a workaround is to remove -k and -K

I use

```
syndaemon -i 0.8 -d -R
```

and everything works fine.

Comment: Same as https://askubuntu.com/a/192579/158442?

Comment: no because the bug is in the implementation of the -k and -K and that is the bug which re-enables keypad unwanted while typing

Comment: This is the only answer that actually address the question "how to monitor syndaemon"